# Не хочет работать animate в jQuery. Почему?

Tags: jquery

Вот так работает:

```
$(".class").css({ backgroundColor: "#FCFCD8" });
```

вот так не хочет:

```
$(".class").animate({ backgroundColor: "#FCFCD8" }, 2000);
```

Что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> ... most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`,
>   or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color plugin is used).

то есть

> ... большинство нечисловых свойств не могут быть анимированы,
>   используя базовую функциональность jQuery. (Например, `width`, `height`
>   или `left` могут быть анимированы, a `background-color` - не может, если
>   не использовать плагин jQuery.Color.)